# AwesomeWM wallpaper change

Tags: linux, linux-mint, awesome-wm

When I am using Awesome-WM under Linux Mint 13 "Maya" MATE, sometimes I need to open the File Manager "Caja". But when I launch `caja`, the wallpaper changes to the one I set under MATE instead of the one in `rc.lua`. I have tried

```
sudo gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background draw-background false
```

but it seems useless.

How can I keep my settings under awesome-wm? Or I should set the 2 backgrounds the same?

Comment: This probably belongs on superuser rather than stackoverflow.

Comment: You should try launching a different file manager, to see if the problem persists, or if it's just with `caja`. As @CameronSkinner noted, you would have more helpful suggestions and answers on [superuser](https://superuser.com) and/or [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try setting your wallpaper using `feh`.
Create a `.fehbg` file in your `$HOME` and put this in:

```
feh --bg-scale '/path/to/wallpaper.jpg'
```

..then save it.

Then in your autostart script just add `sh $HOME/.fehbg &` then try restarting your DE. If it still persists after opening `Caja`, then I am not sure about that since I am totally unfamiliar with `Caja`, rather, I am not familiar with `MATE` at all.

Comment: Thanks, I am not using `mate` now, but when using `nautilus` it works!

Answer (score 1):

I think what's happening is that `caja` is set to 'manage' your desktop. That means it'll change your wallpaper to the one set in MATE, and probably display desktop icons as well, e.g., Computer, Home, etc. This has always been a problem for me when using alternative window managers on Ubuntu, because `nautilus` does it as well. With `nautilus` the behaviour can be turned off using the terminal flag `--no-desktop`. `caja` seems to be a descendant of `nautilus` and a quick Google shows references to the same terminal option for it as well. So I suggest you try

```
caja --no-desktop
```

and see if that works for you.